# Consideration on synchronous circuits

Tags: digital-logic, synchronous

I was considering the synchronous design model.

If I understand it correctly, it can be represented as so : [image]

(excuse the awful schematic made with Paint)

The state switches within a stage are conditionned by the states of the previous stage and are triggered on the rising edge of the clock.

What I wondered was the following: on the rising edge, the stage number n switches, but so does the stage n+1, whose inputs are function of the states of the stage n.

That would mean the switch of the D input of a flip-flop is simultaneous to the clock, which lead to an indeterminate state of the flip-flop.

The problem may be solved if there is some delay between the Q outputs of the stage n an the D inputs of the stage n+1, and that delay should be greater or equal to the hold-time of the flip-flops of the stage n+1.

But that would mean that the circuit wouldn't work for any flip-flop.

Am I wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: "But that would mean that the circuit wouldn't work for any flip-flop." I'm not following your reasoning here, why do you think this would be a problem?

Comment: The D input of any flip-flop of the circuit holds until the state of the previous stage changes. And the previous stage state change is triggered by the clock, that means it changes on the clock.

Comment: So, the D input switches on the clock, what is pretty bad, because the D input must hold a certain time (the hold-time)

Comment: And if you change one particular flip-flop, it may have a different hold-time.

Comment: The output won't change until a certain time after the clock. You then have the delay through whatever logic determines the D inputs for the next stage. You also have a setup time prior to the clock edge by when your D input needs to be set. Changes to the D input after the output has changed state aren't going to affect it.

Comment: I've understood it, but what if the hold-time of the flip-flop is greater than the propogation delay of the combinatory logic part + the propogation delay of the previous flip-flops ?

Comment: Then it would be pretty much useless as a D-type flip flop. The hold time is partly determined by the propagation delay from clock to output anyway so it won't happen in practice.

Comment: Ok! That mean it's not a consequence of the synchronous design. It's just that hold-time is in practice so negligible compared to the propogation delay of all that stuff that it's never a problem.

Comment: By the way, is the previous state of a flip-flop guaranteed to be hold and defined during a certain time after the clock has triggered it?

Comment: I suggest you have a good look at how a D type flip flop actually works and understand what sort of things cause a problem and what don't.

Comment: But in case, per example, of a really fast register bank in the first stage and a really fast combinatory logic part, with an overall propogation delay, let's say of 1 ns. If on the next stage, there is a slow RAM with a hold-time of 3 ns, would it be an issue there? (I don't know wether these times are realistic)

Comment: You always have the chance for problems if you mix fast and slow logic, it's simply a case of designing your circuit to suit what you're trying to do.

Comment: I indeed found that the contamination delay of the previous stage must be greater than the hold time of the current register